# How to return prematurely from lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to trigger a lambda when I drop a new file in a bucket.
This code is working as in it's detecting the file and send the info to my API.

I'm also trying to ignore every file not name "text.txt" but I can't figure out how to return from the lambda inside that `includes` block

```
const http = require('http');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const srcRegion =  event.Records[0].awsRegion;
    const srcEventTime =  event.Records[0].eventTime;
    const srcEventName =  event.Records[0].eventName;
    const srcIP =  event.Records[0].requestParameters.sourceIPAddress;
    const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    const srcETag = event.Records[0].s3.object.eTag;

    if (!srcKey.includes('text.txt')) {
      resolve('Not original file');
    }

    const data = JSON.stringify({
      lambda: {
        src_bucket: srcBucket,
        src_key: srcKey,
        src_region: srcRegion,
        src_event_time: srcEventTime,
        src_event_name: srcEventName,
        src_ip: srcIP,
        src_etag: srcETag
      }
    });
    const options = {
        host: '*****************'
        path: '*****************'
        port: '*****************'
        method: '*****************'
        headers: '*****************'
    };

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
       res.on('data', function(d) {
         console.log(d);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      // reject(e.message);
      resolve('Error');
    });

    // send the request
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
    resolve('Success');
  });
};
```

Comment: `return resolve(...);`

Comment: or `return reject(...)` - depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: @griFlo
I want to exit the lambda and don't do anything. kind of a if/else.

If its the original file trigger the request part, if its something like "text_copy.txt" just ignore it

Comment: You *can* use a promise here (as you're doing) but you don't need to. It will be simpler if you don't. Being async, the return value is a promise anyway without you doing anything. Without a promise you'd just `return 'your text'` to exit, for a failure `throw new Error('blah')` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the `includes` block: `context.done(undefined, 'Done.')`